# Check my answers: Dominant strategy.

Tags: self-learning, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

[image]

I saw another question on Game theory.

My answer

for part a

the nash equlibria (T, L) and (B,R).

for part-b, Player-1's action T is strictly diominated. So Player1 never choose T.

For part c, Player-2's actions L and R are similar. So, no diominant strategy.

For part d, (M,R) and (B,R).

**Are my answers correct? Please check these:)**

Comment: A strategy is dominant if the player gets a higher payoff using it no matter what his opponent plays. (There is also a weak version, that is, a higher or equal payoff.)  A dominant strategy equilibrium is where every player has a dominant strategy, that is, they all don't care what anyone else plays.

Comment: Then, is the answer for part a correct? Secondly, for part-b, Player-1's action T is strictly diominated. So Player1 never choose T. For part c, Player-2's actions L and R are similar. So, no diominant strategy. For part d, (M,R) and (B,R). Are my answers correct? Please check these. I need to learn true ones:( thanks @Trurl

Comment: Hi @B11b, are you allowing mixed (probabilistic) strategies, or are you just supposed to find the *pure* Nash equilibria?  I will write up an answer for you if you let me know which of these two you mean.

Comment: I know pure nash equilibrium @Goos

Comment: It looks like (M,R) is also a pure strategy Nash Equilibrium; neither player has an incentive to deviate, although the best reply is not unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Nash Equilibria**

If player 2 will play L, player 1 should play T or M.  If player 2 will play R, player 1 should play M or B.  And so on.  Circling payoff values in this way, we get
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
  & L   & R   \\
\hline
T & \boxed{1}, \boxed{1} & 0, 0 \\
M & \boxed{1}, \boxed{1} & \boxed{2}, \boxed{1} \\
B & 0, 0 & \boxed{2}, \boxed{1} \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

The Nash equilibria are therefore $(T,L), (M,L), (M,R), (B,R)$, which is two additional equilibria from what you listed.
Any box with both numbers circled is a Nash equilibrium.

**Dominant strategies**

For player 1, M is a weak dominant strategy since it always does *at least* as good as the other options.  Another way to notice this is to note that in the row for M, both the payoffs for player 1 are circled.  By the same reasoning T and B are not dominant strategies.

For player 2, there is no dominant strategy, even a weak one, because if player 1 plays T, then L is better than R, and if player 1 plays B, then R is better than L.

**Dominant strategy equilibrium**

Since player 2 has no dominant strategy, there can be no dominant strategy equilibrium.

Comment: I understand thank you:))